# Ordering dates for 4 weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-order-by

I am writing a SQL query that pulls some information for the last 4 weeks.
 I am seeing two issues with my results (see below).

**First problem** is that when I look back four weeks, the range should be August 10 - September 6. When I order by 'Day of the Month', the dates in September get moved to the top of the results when they should actually be at the end. So my results should start from 10 (august) and end at 6 (September).

**Second problem** is I'm missing a few random dates (3, 4, 13, 27).

```
Day of the Month    Number of X
1                   125
2                   77
5                   5
6                   23
10                  145
11                  177
12                  116
14                  2
15                  199
16                  154
17                  134
18                  140
19                  154
21                  8
22                  166
23                  145
24                  151
25                  107
26                  79
28                  3
29                  151
30                  163
31                  147
```

Here a general version of my query:

```
DECLARE @startDate datetime, @endDate datetime;
SET @startDate = dateadd(day, -28, GETDATE());
SET @endDate = dateadd(day, -1, GETDATE());

Select DATEPArt(dd, Time) AS 'Day of the Month', count(*) AS ' Number of X' 
from SomeTable ST
where Time >= @startDate
AND Time <  @endDate 
group by DATEPArt(dd, Time)   
order by 'Day of the Month'
```

Comment: If you are missing date data, you might have to create and use a calendar table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem you can order by date to get the correct date order. I use convert to get a time-free date so that the entries group correctly.

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime;
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(day, -28, GETDATE());
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE());

SELECT 
DATEPART(dd, Convert(date, Time)) AS 'Day of the Month', COUNT(*) AS ' Number of X' 
FROM SomeTable ST
WHERE Time >= @StartDate
AND Time <  @EndDate 
GROUP BY Convert(date, Time) 
ORDER BY Convert(date, Time)
```

As for the missing days, this is more complicated as the data needs to be there for the group-by to work.

One option is to create a temporary table with all the dates in, then join in the data. This will still leave a row where the join does not find any data, and can get a "zero" count.

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime;
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(day, -28, GETDATE());
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE());

--Create temporary table with all days between the two dates
;WITH d(d) AS 
(
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @StartDate), 0))
  FROM ( SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1) 
    n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) - 1
    FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY [object_id] ) AS n
)
--Join in our query to the table temporary table
SELECT  
    DATEPART(dd, d.d) AS 'Day of the Month', 
    COUNT(Time) AS ' Number of X' 
FROM d LEFT OUTER JOIN SomeTable ST ON DATEPART(dd, d.d) = DATEPART(dd, Time) 
                              AND Time >= @StartDate 
                              AND Time <  @EndDate 
GROUP BY d.d
ORDER BY d.d
```

Comment: Ordering this way works fine in ms-sql although may not work in other forms of sql. I've edited the order by to use the column index instead.

Comment: Thanks James, unfortunately though, all that does is add a column that shows the month. The dates for September are still at the top.

Comment: I cannot reproduce, if the query is run the results are ordered by month then day of the month. Although I notice I did not change the query back to how you have it. Could you copy the second query and retry?

Comment: James, not sure what I need to enter in place of [object_id]. Could you please clarify?

Comment: You do not need to replace the temp table constructor query, this simply creates a table with all the dates between the start and end date. Just need to change "SomeTable" with your table name, and all the "Time" columns to the name of your date column.

Comment: why not just order by the date field, is the date parting really necessary? as December to January could cause a problem with year now and if you're going to part out the year, why not just sort by the date to begin with and avoid all the date parting...

Comment: Glad to help :)